# How to use a query as a parameter for a function?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I just refactored into a power query function  some code that process tables that has an specific structure.

Now, I need to pass another PowerQuery query (that returns a table with a compatible structure)  to this function, but the parameter manager only allows to use strings, therefore I need to obtain access to the referenced table using an string with its name.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you give a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this? A concrete example would help greatly.

Comment: I think you have chosen the wrong language to program this solution - Power Query is not that dynamic.